# Bootstrap 4 row with left & right aligned buttons on the bottom of div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have some buttons on a row, two aligned on the left and one aligned on the right as follows:

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;    
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  /* Vertically center the text there */
  line-height: 60px;      
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.fa-arrows-alt {
  color: rgb(231, 81, 37);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/23ac9aaa92.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
      A div here
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Edit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Delete</button>
      <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt fa-2x float-right"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I would like the buttons to force them to be always on the bottom of the div, **above the footer**. I tried using bottom: 0 and position absolute, fixed but I received an unexpected result. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the flexbox classes that are built in to Bootstrap. You just need CSS to make sure the body is `display:flex` and full height...

https://www.codeply.com/go/lEaF85K1KU

CSS

```
body {
   height:100vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-fill {
   flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<main class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column flex-fill">
    <div class="row flex-column flex-fill">
        <div class="col-12 flex-fill">
            A div here
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Delete</button>
            <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt fa-2x float-right"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<footer class="container-fluid bg-light py-3">
   Sticky Footer
</footer>
```

**Note:** The `flex-fill` utility class will be [included in the next Bootstrap 4.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/2137d61eacbd962ea41e16a492da8b1d1597d3d9) release. So after that release the extra CSS for flex-fill won't be needed.

Answer (score 2):

use bootstrap 4 position-absolute predefined class and add bottom:0

```css
.position-absolute {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid position-absolute">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 btn-row">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Edit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">Delete</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm float-right">Full Screen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get something to stick to the bottom of the screen, do

```
<footer class="fixed-bottom">
```

To get buttons to go left and right give each button a class of “pull-left” or “pull-right”

Comment: My mistake. I would like to be a the bottom of a div, not as a footer. I corrected the description.